# Converting a curve to a diagonal line with Cairo (in Avant Window Navigator on Linux)

Tags: c, linux, desktop, cairo, dock

I'm currently trying to modify Avant Window Navigator's "Lucido mode" code in order to replace the separator's/s' curves with diagonal lines.

The part of the (Cairo) code that governs the curviness is present from lines 330 to 334 in the following file on GitHub: [link](https://github.com/Sprezzatech/avant-window-navigator/blob/7968e280cedc738f4b1bdada3a4af8c3e891a818/src/awn-background-lucido.c#L330-L334)

```
{ /* Oblique */
  gfloat xm = ( *xs + xf ) / 2.0;
  cairo_curve_to (cr, xm, *ys, xm, yf, xf, yf);
}
```

In order to make the goal easier to understand, here is an image of what AWN Lucido looks like right now and what I want it to look like:

[image: Example]

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me with getting the code right to make the separator a straight, diagonal line.

Thank you very much for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Info on drawing curves with Cairo can be found [here](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Paths.html#cairo-curve-to).

A four point Bezier curve looks like this:

[image]

`cairo_curve_to` takes the current pen position for `p0` and its arguments are the next 3 points.

So you could make `cairo_curve_to` draw a straight line by passing the same point for each argument. This is kinda wasteful but not a serious issue for you probably.

It looks like if you pass the end position for both arguments of `_line_from_to` it will degenerate to drawing a straight line, as you want. e.g. if the call to that function was `_line_from_to(cr, &x, &y, x2, y2)` change it to `_line_from_to(cr, &x2, &y2, x2, y2)`.

Alternatively, change the code for `_line_from_to` to be

```
static void 
_line_from_to ( cairo_t *cr,
                gfloat *xs,
                gfloat *ys,
                gfloat xf,
                gfloat yf)
{
  cairo_line_to (cr, xf, yf);
  *xs = xf;
  *ys = yf;
}
```

If you want more info on `cairo_curve_to`, see [this example](http://cairographics.org/samples/curve_to/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Unfortunately the block of code that you have provided makes errors during compiling and, as I don't have experience with using Cairo, I couldn't figure out a fix. When I try to compile AWN with this code in the awn-background-lucido.c file I get this error: http://pastebin.com/rFpL9DjU

Comment: Fantastic! It worked like a charm this time! Thank you very much for your assistance :)